# Android sdk 4.2 and cordova 2.3 emulator issues

Tags: android, cordova, android-emulator

I have installed on mac lion Android sdk 4.2 & phonegap cordova 2.3. eclipse Indigo, using cordova's setup I created a project.  I made no changes
 I get an error [2013-02-02 21:34:46 - And2] Failed to install And2.apk on device 'emulator-5554!
[2013-02-02 21:34:46 - And2] (null)
[2013-02-02 21:34:46 - And2] Launch canceled!

Next I Install on windows 7 Android 4.2 , eclipse Indio, cordova 2.3, I create a project using  cordova standard way ( No changes made) I run the project on the emulator it runs, cool, next time (any time after that ) I run I get the error
webcore EventHub.removeMessages (int what = 107) is not supported before the WebViewCore is set up.

What is the problem ? I just cant proceed, any help?

Answer (score 0):

I dunno if this will help, but I suggest using android sdk 2.3. Most phones seem to be running this at a minimum

Comment: This is the latest SDK downloaded on Feb 2. its windows installer_r21.0.1-windows.exe & Mac android-sdk_r21.0.1-macosx.zip

Comment: android sdk version, not the installer